# Update Joomla 1.5.22 to php greater than 5.4

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla1.5

My old Joomla site is using a rule in the htaccess code that is forcing it to run at a non-supported PHP version 5.4. My host just quit supporting this version of php. Does anyone know what version of php Joomla 1.5.22 will support? How do I add it to my website and how to change my htaccess file (currently the line in htaccess is: 'AddType application/x-httpd-php .php').

Any assistance would be much appreciated, website is down with 500 error.

Comment: Your version of PHP was end-of-lifed seven years ago, and your Joomla version is 13 years old. It's not likely to run on any currently supported version of PHP.

Comment: "How do I add it to my website" - You'd need to contact your host. What (are the lowest) versions of PHP that your host supports? [This old question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/786/28) on the [Joomla stack](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/) suggests PHP 5.6 might be OK (but that's still "old"). But it's also going to depend on what plugins you are using. The Joomla stack might be better suited to this question.